# How to apply a function to an array in MatLab with multiple arguments?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, functional-programming

I have an array called `contin` array like `[10,100,1000]`, and I'd like to apply a function called `transcontin` to that array.  I know that the way to do this is `arrayfunc(@transcontin, contin)`, if there is only one input to the function.

But, the function `transcontin` takes three inputs: `Temp`, `b`, and `H`.  And, I need it to pass the values of the array into the function `transcontin` as `b`.

But, I have to loop through values of `Temp` and `H`.  These values of `Temp` and `H` stay the same throughout each application to `contin`.

How do I accomplish this?  How do I do `arrayfunc(@transcontin, contin)` but pass in the other two parameters that do not come in as an array?

Example input: `contin=[10, 100, 1000]`

Function:

```
function result=transcontin(Temp,b,h)
   result=b+Temp^h;
end
```

Let's say I want to fix Temp and h, and pass the elements of the array in as `b`:

```
Temp=5;
h=(1/3);
```

The output, after I do something like this upon the suggestion from @Edric `arrayfun(@b transcontin(Temp, b, h), contin)`, should be a vector transformed into:

```
[10+5^(1/3), 100+5^(1/3), 1000+5^(1/3)]
```

how to accomplish this?

Comment: Provide an example of input/output/intermediate matrices

Comment: if i understand your question, you have some fixed parameters but `arrayfun`need array as input. You can use `repmat` in order to clone your parameters. Something like: `arrayfun(@thefunction,contin,repmat(b,1000,1)` if you have 1000 loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "bind" in the constant arguments to an anonymous function handle, something like this (I think):

```
out = arrayfun(@(x) transcontin(Temp, x, H), contin)
```

The first argument to `arrayfun` is the anonymous function handle - that syntax creates a function that takes a single argument as required by `arrayfun`, and "binds" in the constant values `Temp` and `H`. More in the doc here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Comment: Matlab doesn't like the syntax of `@(x) transcontin(Temp, x, H),`...  It doesn't like the space between them

Comment: @Hunle. That sounds specious. What exact error do you get?